# python - if not in list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, notin

I have two lists:

```
mylist = ['total','age','gender','region','sex']
checklist = ['total','civic']
```

I have to work with some code I have inherited which looks like this:

```
for item in mylist:
    if item in checklist:
        do something:
```

How can I work with the code above to tell me that **'civic' is not in mylist**?.

This would've been the ideal way to do it but I cant use it, don't ask me why.

```
for item in checklist:
    if item not in mylist:
        print item
```

Outcome:

```
civic
```

Comment: it works for me with Python 2.7.  "if item not in mylist"   or "if not item in mylist" both works

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about this?

```
for item in mylist:
    if item in checklist:
        pass
    else:
       # do something
       print item
```

Comment: it works for me with Python 2.7. "if item not in mylist" or "if not item in mylist" both works

Comment: Actually the the preferred syntax is `a not in b`

Answer (score 55):

Your code should work, but you can also try:

```
    if not item in mylist :
```

Comment: This makes the most logical sense to me and works!  Thanks Will - not sure why this is on the bottom. Lets push it up!

Answer (score 4):

if I got it right, you can try

```
for item in [x for x in checklist if x not in mylist]:
    print (item)
```

Answer (score 1):

You better do this syntax

```
if not (item in mylist):  
    Code inside the if
```

Comment: actually, PEP8 prefers "item not in mylist" over "not item in mylist". https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations (analogous to "is not" vs "not ... is")