# comparing user's input to a list in Python

Tags: python, list

how would I check if something is not in a list?
this is my current code:

```
for line not in line: open("drivers_details.txt"):
               if reg not in line:
                  name=input("what is your name?\n")
                  address=input("what is your address\n")
                  print (reg,name,address,"%0.2f"%average_time,"MPH")
```

(I tried to use "not in" but it didn't work)

Comment: You can't run a loop over something that is not in the list. A loop basically runs over every value within the list, so obviously this loop is never going to be true. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22833893/python-if-not-in-list for solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
for line in open("drivers_details.txt"):
    if reg not in line:
        etc.
```